# LinkedList recursion problem using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for help solving this recursion problem: Given a linked list of indeterminate length, composed of nodes that store a reference to the next node....how can you return the list in reverse?

For example, node A --> B --> C --> D should return D-->C-->B-->A. The function is given any node and should return that list in reverse.

A node would consist of a couple values; an integer (i) and a *next* property which is the pointer to the next node.

```
const traverseList = (node) => {
    if(node.next !== null) traverseList(node);
    else return;
}
```

I'm trying this code but it's not working. Just looking for the missing pieces, please. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please post a dummy example of the linked list node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are on the right path, just print it when you are returning from each node.

```
const traverseList = (node) => {
   if (!node) return;

   traverseList(node.next);
   console.log(node.value); // or whatever you want to output
}
```

Comment: Think you want to test for `(!node)` rather than `(!node.next)` otherwise you don't print the last node.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding the printing out part. In your example, if the function is given the C node first it will call itself again and then return because D is the last node. So it wouldn't print, right?

Comment: @fumeng, its like this, you send your linklist first node to the function (which has the value A), then the calling part is like this A->B->C->D->null. Now the method will return till the root of execution, which is in order null ->D->C->B->A, now except for null (since it will call the return; statement in the if condition), the rest will print their value, which is D->C->B->A. I hope you understand this.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. I get some of it but I still don't understand why the method will return 'til the root of execution. That's the only part I don't get.

Comment: well when you code returns from null, you actually go back to the recursive call statement and then call console.log(), since no statement after that remains, a return is called behind the scenes (and this occurs many times since its recursion), therefore the statement 'till the root of execution'.

Answer (score 1):

1) Store a reference to current(initially head), next(initially null), previous(initially null) node

2) Set tail to head, if your using a tail pointer

3) Traverse this list setting next to current.next, current.next to previous, previous to current, and finally current to next

4) Depending on how you do it after the loop, you must set current.next to previous and head to current

I have included both iterative and recursive solutions below.

```js
class Node {
 constructor(value, next){
  this.value = value;
  this.next = next;
 }
}

class LinkedList {
 constructor(){
  this.size = 0;
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
 }
 
 add(value){
  const node = new Node(value, null);
  
  if(this.head === null){
   this.head = node;
   this.tail = node;
  } else {
   this.tail.next = node;
   this.tail = node;
  }
  
  this.size++;
 }
 
 traverse(){
  let current = this.head;
  
  while(current != null){
   console.log(current.value);
   current = current.next;
  }
 }
 
 reverse(){
   let current = this.head;
   let previous = null;
   let next = null;
   this.tail = current;
   
   while(current != null && current.next != null){
      next = current.next;
      current.next = previous;
      previous = current;
      current = next;
   }
   
   current.next = previous;
   this.head = current;
 }
 
 _reverseRecursively(node){
  if(node == null){
   return null;
  }
  
  if(node.next == null){
   this.head = node;
   return node;
  }
  
  let nextNode = this._reverseRecursively(node.next);
  nextNode.next = node;
  node.next = null;
  return node;
 }
 
 reverseRecursively(){
  this.tail = this.head;
  this._reverseRecursively(this.head);
 }
}

const list = new LinkedList();

list.add(10);
list.add(12);
list.add(14);
console.log("Original List");
list.traverse();
list.reverse();
console.log("Reversed List - using loop");
list.traverse();
list.reverseRecursively();
console.log("Reversed List - using recursion");
list.traverse();
```